# Setting Moxy as default jaxb implementation provider

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I was trying to set Moxy as my default JAXB provider cause i need another algorithm convention for `XmlElement` names, so i found very useful `XMLNameTransformer`.

I create `package-info`

```
@XmlNameTransformer(NameXMLPattern.class)
package com.onix.validadores.messages;

import com.onix.validadores.utils.NameXMLPattern;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlNameTransformer;
```

And `jaxb.properties` file

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

But when i make a main to test i get

```
System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(RequestAutorizacion.class).getClass());
```

OUTPUT:

> class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl

But i wanted `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext`

I follow this [tutorial](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)

Comment: Where's [Blaise Doughan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan) when you need him?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i answer my own question but perhaps there is a more elegant solution xD, i just post if someone has the same problem

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I was getting a tea :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jaxb.properties location**

The `jaxb.properties` file needs to go in the same package as one of the classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.  For your use case it would need to go in the same package as the `RequestAutorizacion` class.

**Name Transformer**

Your implementation of name transformer can be in any package you like and does not impact where the `jaxb.properties` file should be located.

Comment: My problem was that i didn't do clean and build .. so this question should be deleted xD